# closing statically created executorservice blocks assigned variables itself?

Tags: java, executorservice

I just wonder explanation of how this code is working

assume we have **Work** class in below

```
 public  class Work  {
    private static ThreadPoolExecutor executorService;

    private  Work(){};

    public static void instansiate(int numberOfThread){
        executorService= (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThread);
    }

    public static void shutDown(){
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    public static ExecutorService getExecutorService() {
        return executorService;
    }

    public static int getThreadCount(){
        return executorService.getCorePoolSize();
    }
}
```

and im calling this class somewhere in method like below

```
 public static void xx() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    Work.instansiate(2);
    System.out.println("Thread count= " + Work.getThreadCount());
    ExecutorService executorService = Work.getExecutorService();
    Future<String> future1 = executorService.submit(new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            return "future1";
        }
    });
    String resFuture1 = future1.get();
    System.out.println(resFuture1);
    Work.shutDown();
    Future<String> future2 = executorService.submit(new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            return "future2";
        }
    });

    String resFuture2 = future2.get();
    System.out.println(resFuture2);

}
```

This code is throwing exception after **Work.shutDown()** line and says  rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@234bef66[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0 ...

I had assigned Work.getExecutorService to another executorService how closing **Work executorservice** can block assigned one.

Comment: Until you call `Work.getExecutorService` again you're still holding a reference to the original (now shut down) `ExecutorService`.

Comment: From [the documentation of the shutdown method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown%28%29): “Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted.”

Comment: @Powerlord I know after shutting down you cannot submit new task . I mean i had assigned 'Work.getExecutorService' to a variable **executorService** im closing Work class executorService. how this affect assigned variable?

Comment: Everything is pass by value in Java, even reference types.  So, even if you update Work's `executorService`, anything that called `Work.getExecutorService` still has the old reference.

Comment: @Powerlord i agree with u, **Work's executorService** is assigned a variable (executorService) before shut down already. So it has old reference. So it shouldn't be affected of closing ** Work's executorService**. What im missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually executorService holding same reference with Work.executorService(), Thus it was affected of closing Work's executorservice.